# remove function in my linked list not working

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am supposed to build a method that will remove the first instance of a given value in a singly-linked list. However, whenever I try to test this method it will get stuck and I have to force the code to terminate.

edit: following advice, I have made a modified version method Contains that now works well and eliminates pointless repetition of Contains. so happily now the code works as it should!

Here is my code for the method:

```
public boolean remove(Anything m) {
    //INCOMPLETE
    
     if (this.first==null) {
        System.out.println("there are no values in the list");
        return false;
    }
    
    boolean returnValue;
    returnValue=false;
    if (this.contains(m)==true) { 
       Node temp=first;
        while(temp.next!=null) {
            if (temp.next.data==m) {
                temp=temp.next.next;
                temp.next=null;
                returnValue=true;
        
    }
            else 
            returnValue=false;
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Here is my code for testing the method:

```
 list13.addFirst("node5"); list13.addFirst("node4"); list13.addFirst("node3"); list13.addFirst("node2"); list13.addFirst("node1");
         System.out.println("5-element list: " + list13);
System.out.println("Testing remove...");
        System.out.println(list13.remove("node3"));
```

and just in case, here is the prebuilt code my assignment came with, if needed:

````
public class CS2LinkedList<Anything>
{  
    // the Node class is a private inner class used (only) by the LinkedList class
    private class Node
    {
        private Anything data;
        private Node next;
        
        public Node(Anything a, Node n)
        {
            data = a;
            next = n;
        }
    }
    
    private Node first;
    private Node last;
    
    
    public CS2LinkedList()
    {
        first = null;
    }
    
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (first == null);
    }
    
    public void addFirst(Anything d)
    {
         Node temp = first;
         first = new Node(d,temp);
    }
    
    
    public void clear()
    {
        first = null;
    }
    
    public boolean contains(Anything value)
    {
        for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next)
        {
            if (value.equals(curr.data))              {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();  //String result = "";
        for (Node curr = first; curr != null; curr = curr.next)
            result.append(curr.data + "->");  //result = result + curr.data + "->";
        result.append("[null]");
        return result.toString();   //return result + "[null]";
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Have youbtried to use debugger? Also you do not need to use `contains()` in you remove method since it will iterate over the whole list

Comment: Agree with Ivan.  Look at the implementation of contains -- it does just what you want, except that it doesn't remove the node.  Your problem is that you keep iterating through the list after you've removed the node, so you will set returnValue back to false.  Also, your steps for removing the node have a bug.  Try using a couple of local variables so that you don't get confused.  Remember that when you find the node, you'll need to know what the previous node was because you have to change its next pointer.

Comment: since this is a singly-linked list, how would I keep track of the previous node?

Comment: *since this is a singly-linked list, how would I keep track of the previous node?* - you would not. Singly-linked list elements, [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list), does not contain a reference to the previous element.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- At a match, you are reassigning to `temp` the node that follows *after* the node to be deleted, and *then* you clear `temp.next`. That is breaking the list *after* the node to be deleted.
- The while loop does not change the value of `temp` when the `if` condition is not true. So the loop can hang.
- You can stop the search when you have identified the node to delete. By consequence you don't need the `else` inside the `while` loop.

```
        while(temp.next!=null) {
            if (temp.next.data==m) {
                // skip the node by modifying `temp.next`:
                temp.next = temp.next.next;
                returnValue=true;
                break; // we removed the targeted node, so get out
            }
            temp = temp.next; // must move to next node in the list
        }
```

It is a pity that you first iterate the list with `this.contains(m)`, only to iterate it again to find the same node *again*. I would just remove that  `if` line, and execute the loop that follows any way: it will detect whether the list contains the value or not.

Be aware that your function has no provision for removing the first node of the list. It starts comparing *after* the first node. You may want to cover this boundary case.